# Mobile and tablet specific websites

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, css

I understand the concept of using @media-queries in building responsive websites, and how as a **single website**, it works across the different platforms...but what is the best way to create a **separate** or **secondary website**, dedicated for just mobile and tablet devices?

If I have the following website - `mywebsite.com` and create a folder on my directory, called **`m`** for example, so that I have a sub-domain name along the lines of `m.mywebsite.com`, how do I tell the device to display the secondary website  `m.mywebsite.com` on certain devices, instead of `mywebsite.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ it contains every Language.

Answer (score 2):

As in the previous answer, I use detectmobilebrowsers, in fact the jQuery plugin. Then all you need to do is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.browser.mobile && $.cookie("mobile")!="false") { //the cookie is set only if a user on the mobile website prefers to use the desktop website
    window.location.href = "http://m.mywebsite.com/";
  }
}
```